# Running unit tests for Hadoop 2.4.0 jobs in Standalone Mode using Local Runner

Tags: maven, unit-testing, hadoop, junit

When using previous versions of Hadoop, I typically build junit tests for the entire job (both mapper and reducer) and run the test by invoking maven or directly from the IDE itself. There was no installation of hadoop anywhere on the system. I used the following properties to ensure that the local in-process runner was used:

```
config.set("mapred.job.tracker", "local");
config.set("fs.default.name", "file:///test-fs");
```

These tests ran successfully.

I upgraded to newer version of Hadoop (2.4.0) to take advantage of the new API. I want to be able to do the same thing with my units as before. The properties that I now use are:

```
config.set("fs.default.name", "file:///test-fs");
config.set("mapreduce.jobtracker.address", "local");
config.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "local");
```

I construct the configuration object in my tests and pass it to the actual code from which the Job object is created.

However, this doesn't work and I get the following error:

java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.(Cluster.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.(Cluster.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1251)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
    at com.roblox.games.retention.W1ReturnFromNewPlayersThePreviousWeekCalculatorJob1.calculateW1ReturnJob1(W1ReturnFromNewPlayersThePreviousWeekCalculatorJob1.java:68)
    at com.roblox.games.retention.W1ReturnFromNewPlayersThePreviousWeekCalculatorDriver.calculateW1Return(W1ReturnFromNewPlayersThePreviousWeekCalculatorDriver.java:74)
    at com.roblox.games.retention.W1ReturnFromNewPlayersThePreviousWeekCalculatorDriverTest.testCase(W1ReturnFromNewPlayersThePreviousWeekCalculatorDriverTest.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? To reiterate, I don't have any hadoop installation nor binaries on the host where I'm running these tests.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with hadoop 2.7.1 and fixed it by adding a dependency which provides protocol implementation for standalone mode, the name of the class is org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalClientProtocolProvider

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You don't need to set "mapred.job.tracker" or "fs.default.name" because the standalone runner is loaded from classpath automatically.